# HTML Table in which td can be an inner HTML Table, i have a function and buttons that filter the Table, but i want to ignore the inner Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

i have an HTML Table which i generate out of my database.
It contains information about  machines and their status etc., these informations are parsed out of emails that contain HTML Tables about the machines

That is why i have a click to open/hide `<td>` in every tr where i show the "original" HTML Table of the Mail for more details and to better traceability of the results.

All java script functions worked until i added the HTML. Because my filter and search functions iterate through the `<tr>` and the `<td>` tags, so instead of td.length = 2000 i now have something like td.length = 200000, but i don't want to iterate through them , because i already parsed that info in the Table with filters etc

So my questions is what is the best way to ignore the HTML in my search function ?

I tried a class like `<td id ="ignore me">` or should i do something different like removing it from the table and make a pop up window for it ?

Here is a very simplified version of my HTML Table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nested Table Example</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>machine</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>timesinceLastCheck 3</th>
                <th>Original HTML from Email (Inner Table)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 3</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 1, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 1, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 2, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 2, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 3, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 3, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 3</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 4, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 4, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

that is my search/filter function

```js
   function searchTable() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("machineTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        
       

        // Get selected radio button value for filter
        var selectedFilter = document.querySelector('input[name="filter"]:checked').value.toUpperCase();
        // Get selected radio button value for days
        var selectedDays = document.querySelector('input[name="days"]:checked').value;

        // Loop through all table rows
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) { 
            if (i !== 0) { // Check if the row is not the first row (header row)
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                alert("länge der tr")
                alert (tr.length)
                var matchFound = false;
                // Loop through all table columns
                //td.length -1 entfernt
                for (var j = 0; j < 9 ; j++) { 
                    
                    var cell = td[j];
                    if (cell) {
                        txtValue = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;
                        // Check if the cell text contains the filter text, matches the selected filter, and days condition
                        alert(td[i]);
                        alert(i);
                        if ((selectedFilter === "ALL" || td[4].innerText.toUpperCase() === selectedFilter) && 
                            txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 &&
                            (selectedDays === "ALL" || parseInt(td[7].innerText) >= parseInt(selectedDays))) {
                            matchFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Hide or show the row based on match
                if (matchFound) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: the idea of using the querySelectorAll() from James was very good

i then used the solution given in the comments by CarstenMassmann:

```
let tr = table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr");
```

this gives me the correct number of rows, in the innerloop i just iterate every tr with the numberOfColumns because i still get too much td elements, and i did not figure it out yet how

but with the static numberOfColumns it works for me, but my search function will still search through the inner HTML what can cause performance issues

Comment: It's hard to diagnose anything without a code example; please include a minimal reproducible example with your question.

Comment: Show us the selector or code that chooses which TDs to iterate through.

Comment: code of javaScript ? or the HTML or both ?

Comment: You can use `td.innerText` instead of `td.innerHTML`. That will ignore the HTML tags, just returning the plain text.

Comment: We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see all the working pieces that reproduce your problem.

Comment: i hope the code i provided makes it more clear

Answer (score 1):

You can get only trs which are direct children of the main table like this.

```
tr = table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr");
```

Then within your loop over the trs, you can use a similar technique to get only tds that are direct children of the tr.

```
td = tr[i].querySelectorAll(":scope > td");
```

```js
   function searchTable() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("machineTable");
        
        tr = table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr");
        
       

        // Get selected radio button value for filter
        var selectedFilter = document.querySelector('input[name="filter"]:checked').value.toUpperCase();
        // Get selected radio button value for days
        var selectedDays = document.querySelector('input[name="days"]:checked').value;

        // Loop through all table rows
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) { 
            if (i !== 0) { // Check if the row is not the first row (header row)
                td = tr[i].querySelectorAll(":scope > td");
                alert("länge der tr")
                alert (tr.length)
                var matchFound = false;
                // Loop through all table columns
                //td.length -1 entfernt
                for (var j = 0; j < 9 ; j++) { 
                    
                    var cell = td[j];
                    if (cell) {
                        txtValue = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;
                        // Check if the cell text contains the filter text, matches the selected filter, and days condition
                        alert(td[i]);
                        alert(i);
                        if ((selectedFilter === "ALL" || td[4].innerText.toUpperCase() === selectedFilter) && 
                            txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 &&
                            (selectedDays === "ALL" || parseInt(td[7].innerText) >= parseInt(selectedDays))) {
                            matchFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Hide or show the row based on match
                if (matchFound) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, i added the line with let tr, sadly in my test the tr.length = 2313 but in my test they are only 257 machines and every row represents a machine, so i guess it still using tr of the email html

Comment: @James may have used an unfortunate name, but his collection `tr` exlusively collects _first level_ `<td>`s (those belonging _directly_ to `#machineTable`). N.B.: we are talking about `<td>`s here and _not_ `<tr>`s!

Comment: @SemperVirens, in your script you should of course be using `let tr = table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr");` instead. This will give you all the first level `<tr>`s.

Comment: Sorry yes I was selecting Tds - thanks for pointing out the fix @CarstenMassmann

Comment: @CarstenMassmann with you code it seems to work, it seems this selector just takes tr under tbody meaning the th tr row is not considered because i wondered that top row was always shown, so it seems i dont need the "check if table header" line anymore

Comment: BTW is something like this: td = tr[1].querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr > td"); possible ? or should i just take all td with: td =  table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr > td"); i can find an make the inner loop constant because there is dynamic number of rows (tr) but not a dynamic number of columns (td)

Comment: Because this code td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"); gives me changing values for td.length so i should change it, td = table.querySelectorAll(":scope > tbody > tr > td"); this gives me the correct number of td rows basically outerHTmltable = rows (number of machines) x (number about data of machines), but how can i added into the for loop ? i could make the inner loop like  indexofRow * numberofColumns ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing further comments I decided to demonstrate the whole filtering mechanism here:

```js
const [filt,days,tbody]=["input","select","#machineTable tbody"].map(sel=>document.querySelector(sel)),
      trs=[...tbody.children];
      
function filtTable(){
  const filtRX=new RegExp(filt.value,"i"), daysval=days.value;
  trs.forEach(tr=>{
    const tds=tr.children;
    tr.style.display = filtRX.test(tds[3].textContent) && (daysval=="all" || tds[6].textContent==daysval) 
      ? ""       // show
      : "none";  // hide      
  })
}

document.body.addEventListener("input",filtTable);
filtTable();
```

```css
table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 8px;
        }
```

```html
<input placeholder="please enter a filter string" value="hello">
<select><option>all</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option></select> days
<table id="machineTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>machine</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>timesinceLastCheck 3</th>
                <th>Original HTML from Email (Inner Table)</th>
                <th>something</th>
                <th>else</th>
                <th>column 7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 3</td>
                <td>Hello ...
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 1, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 1, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 5</td>
                <td>Row 1, Cell 6</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
                <td>... my friends and also the group "AbC"!
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 2, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 2, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 2, Cell 5</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 6</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
                <td>This is just ...
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 3, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 3, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 5</td>
                <td>Row 3, Cell 6</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 3</td>
                <td>... an example.
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 1</th>
                                <th>Inner Table Header 2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Row 4, Inner Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Row 4, Inner Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 5</td>
                <td>Row 4, Cell 6</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have used a few slightly more advanced concepts here too:

- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): `[filt,days,tbody]=["input","select","#machineTable tbody"].map(sel=>document.querySelector(sel))`  with `Array.map()` (see [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))
  Is an easy way to run a loop and assign the results to an array of constants or variables
- the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) class offers a possibility of comparing case insensitively when using `"i"` as a second argument
- I used `tr.children` (see [children property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)) here to get an [HTMLcollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements. This is an alternative to using `tr.querySelectorAll(":scope td")` which would have returned a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Both lists are slightly different and are not of type "Array"
- the [`...` ("spread syntax")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is then used to convert the `tr.children` collection into a proper array.

Comment: thanks for the input ! i more into backend than frontend that is why im not that good with javascript and HTML and don't into the advance concepts, but i see i can save a lot of time and headache if i would know more advanced concepts